# How to create two independently-scrollable columns in a responsive grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollable

I have a need to present a master-detail screen where the master and detail are each independently-scrollable, side-by-side columns in a responsive grid.  When the browser width is reduced below some threshold, the two columns become stacked, with only a single full-page scroll.

Ideally, I'd like this to be done within twitter-bootstrap. It seems this should be simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine you want something like this in Bootstrap with the .scrollable divs set to  have "overflow:auto" on them.

Bootstrap will make then stack automagically at lower resolutions.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="scrollable"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="scrollable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking