# How to make two independent scrollable columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that contains two `columns`. I am trying to make the columns scrollable independent of each other. The important thing is that I want the tick scrollbar be hidden.

I have only made the row scrollable and the scrollbar is hidden. But I can't make the two columns be so.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKxodX

---

There are a few similar questions have been asked before, but they did not help.

[How can i make 3 independently scrollable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738323/how-can-i-make-3-independently-scrollable-columns)

[How to create two independently-scrollable columns in a responsive grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815108/how-to-create-two-independently-scrollable-columns-in-a-responsive-grid)

[Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

## Update

This is a widget in an App that we use. So, I am can not change style of **body**, **html**, and the parent of **container-fluid**.

Comment: What is the code for the modal? I also don't see a "thin scrollbar on the right side".

Comment: @ZimSystem I updated the code and the  codepen. The modal is a fixed div.

Answer (score 3):

I believe below approach solves your issue. Scrollbars are hidden using trick with `overflow: hidden` and hiding scrollbar with `padding`.

```
.col {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 30px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[-> Codepen.](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/MXqErm)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, you are totally right. [I've updated my codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/MXqErm), could you please let me know if it's OK for you know? You can adjust precise padding's values, of course.

Comment: Thanks. But if you have a an another container at the top, some part of the container that contains the columns is not visible. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yExvQX

Comment: I can't seem to be able to see your issue... I see whole container with columns, nothing is cut-off.

Comment: Try decrease the height of the window

Comment: I've once again [updated my Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/EReEmr). Simple flex-trick denies problems with use of `position: absolute`. Check it, please.